# Reduce by key in python

Tags: python, reduce

I'm trying to think through the most efficient way to do this in python.

Suppose I have a list of tuples:

```
[('dog',12,2), ('cat',15,1), ('dog',11,1), ('cat',15,2), ('dog',10,3), ('cat',16,3)]
```

And suppose I have a function which takes two of these tuples and combines them:

```
def my_reduce(obj1, obj2):
    return (obj1[0],max(obj1[1],obj2[1]),min(obj1[2],obj2[2]))
```

How do I perform an efficient reduce by 'key' where the key here could be the first value, so the final result would be something like:

```
[('dog',12,1), ('cat',16,1)]
```

Comment: did you mean min(obj1[2],obj2[2])

Comment: this looks like something well suited for pandas

Comment: Hey @mgoldwasser, 2 years too late but here's another way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48343896/5858851. BTW, I _am_ the former coworker you think I am.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use your `my_reduce` and `reduce`, you can do it this way. It's fairly short, actually:

Preparation:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

pets = [('dog',12,2), ('cat',15,1), ('dog',11,1), ('cat',15,2), ('dog',10,3), ('cat',16,3)]

def my_reduce(obj1, obj2):
    return (obj1[0],max(obj1[1],obj2[1]),min(obj1[2],obj2[2]))
```

Solution:

```
print [reduce(my_reduce, group)
       for _, group in groupby(sorted(pets), key=itemgetter(0))]
```

Output:

```
[('cat', 16, 1), ('dog', 12, 1)]
```

Comment: May I know what's thy syntax/shorthand you used inside the print statement? It appears a function call followed by for loop and variable defined by the for loop is passed in the function call. reduce(my_reduce, group)
       for _, group in groupby(sorted(pets), key=itemgetter(0))

Comment: @Lee That's a "list comprehension".

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, if you have **pandas** installed:

```
import pandas as pd

l = [('dog',12,2), ('cat',15,1), ('dog',11,1), ('cat',15,2), ('dog',10,3), ('cat',16,3)]

pd.DataFrame(data=l, columns=['animal', 'm', 'n']).groupby('animal').agg({'m':'max', 'n':'min'})
Out[6]: 
         m  n
animal       
cat     16  1
dog     12  1
```

To get the original format:

```
zip(df.index, *df.values.T) # df is the result above
Out[14]: [('cat', 16, 1), ('dog', 12, 1)]
```

Comment: I concure :) ... silly wim and his 0-width spaces :P

Answer (score 7):

I don't think `reduce` is a good tool for this job, because you will have to first use itertools or similar to group the list by the key.  Otherwise you will be comparing `cats` and `dogs` and all hell will break loose!

Instead just a simple loop is fine:

```
>>> my_list = [('dog',12,2), ('cat',15,1), ('dog',11,1), ('cat',15,2)]
>>> output = {}
>>> for animal, high, low in my_list:
...     try:
...         prev_high, prev_low = output[animal]
...     except KeyError:
...         output[animal] = high, low
...     else:
...         output[animal] = max(prev_high, high), min(prev_low, low)
```

Then if you want the original format back:

```
>>> output = [(k,) + v for k, v in output.items()]
>>> output
[('dog', 12, 1), ('cat', 15, 1)]
```

Note this will destroy the ordering from the original list.  If you want to preserve the order the keys first appear in, initialise output with an `OrderedDict` instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use reduce I think this works (it gives you a dict back instead of a list but meh)

```
def my_reduce(obj1, obj2):
    if not isinstance(obj1,dict):
        return reduce(my_reduce,[{},obj1,obj2])
    try:
        obj1[obj2[0]] = max(obj1[obj2[0]][0],obj2[1]),min(obj1[obj2[0]][1],obj2[2])
    except KeyError:
        obj1[obj2[0]] = obj2[1:]
    return obj1

my_list = [('dog',12,2), ('cat',15,1), ('dog',11,1), ('cat',15,2), ('dog',10,3), ('cat',16,3)]
print reduce(my_reduce,my_list)
```

I think both the other solutions are better however

Comment: No, because this would collapse everything to one element, but I want one element per key