# Error using reducebykey: int object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting an error **"int object is unsubscriptable"** while executing the following script :

```
element.reduceByKey( lambda x , y : x[1]+y[1])
```

with element is an key-value RDD and the value is a tuple. Example input:

```
(A, (toto , 10))
(A, (titi , 30))
(5, (tata, 10))
(A, (toto, 10))
```

I understand that the `reduceByKey` function takes (K,V) tuples and apply a function on all the values to get the final result of the reduce.
Like the example given in [ReduceByKey Apache](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html).

Any help please?

Comment: What output do you want? The problem is that `x[1]+y[1]` is an int, not a tuple (which is what `reduceByKey` expect in the next iteration.

Comment: The output expected is `(A , 50) (5, 10)`, but why `reduceByKey` should expect  a tuple in the next iteration? should it keep the same type of the values reduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that will illustrate what's going on.

Let's consider what happens when you call `reduce` on a list with some function `f`:

```
reduce(f, [a,b,c]) = f(f(a,b),c)
```

If we take your example, `f = lambda u, v: u[1] + v[1]`, then the above expression breaks down into:

```
reduce(f, [a,b,c]) = f(f(a,b),c) = f(a[1]+b[1],c)
```

But `a[1] + b[1]` is an integer so there is no `__getitem__` method, hence your error.

In general, the better approach (as shown below) is to use `map()` to first extract the data in the format that you want, and then apply `reduceByKey()`.

---

**A MCVE with your data**

```
element = sc.parallelize(
    [
        ('A', ('toto' , 10)),
        ('A', ('titi' , 30)),
        ('5', ('tata', 10)),
        ('A', ('toto', 10))
    ]
)
```

You can *almost* get your desired output with a more sophisticated reduce function:

```
def add_tuple_values(a, b):
    try:
        u = a[1]
    except:
        u = a
    try:
        v = b[1]
    except:
        v = b
    return u + v

print(element.reduceByKey(add_tuple_values).collect())
```

Except that this results in:

```
[('A', 50), ('5', ('tata', 10))]
```

*Why?* Because there's only one value for the key `'5'`, so there is nothing to reduce.

For these reasons, it's best to first call `map`. To get your desired output, you could do:

```
>>> print(element.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][1])).reduceByKey(lambda u, v: u+v).collect())
[('A', 50), ('5', 10)]
```

---

**Update 1**

Here's one more approach:

You could create `tuple`s in your `reduce` function, and then call `map` to extract the value you want. (Essentially reverse the order of `map` and `reduce`.)

```
print(
    element.reduceByKey(lambda u, v: (0,u[1]+v[1]))
        .map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][1]))
        .collect()
)
[('A', 50), ('5', 10)]
```

---

**Notes**

- Had there been at least 2 records for each key, using `add_tuple_values()` would have given you the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to use Dataframe

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([('A', ('toto', 10)),('A', ('titi', 30)),('5', ('tata', 10)),('A', ('toto', 10))])
rdd.map(lambda (a,(b,c)): (a,b,c)).toDF(['a','b','c']).groupBy('a').agg(sum("c")).rdd.map(lambda (a,c): (a,c)).collect()

>>>[(u'5', 10), (u'A', 50)]
```