# How to understand reduceByKey in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, functional-programming, pyspark, documentation

I am trying to learn Spark and it has been going well so far, except for problems where I need to use functions like reduceByKey or combineByKey on a pair RDD whose values are lists.

I have been trying to find detailed documentation for these functions, that could explain what the arguments actually are, so that I could solve it myself without going to Stack Overflow, but I just cannot find any good documentation for Spark. I have read chapters 3 and 4 from Learning Spark, but to be honest, the explanations for the most complicated functions are very bad.

The problem I am dealing with right now is the following: I have a pair RDD where the key is a string and the value is a list of two elements which are both integers. Something like this: (country, [hour, count]). For each key, I wish to keep only the value with the highest count, regardless of the hour. As soon as I have the RDD in the format above, I try to find the maximums by calling the following function in Spark:

```
reduceByKey(lambda x, y: max(x[1], y[1]))
```

But this throws the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Which does not make any sense to me. I interpreted the arguments x and y as being the values of two keys, e.g. x=[13, 445] and y=[14, 109], but then the error does not make any sense. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306185/5858851) to a different question may help explain to you what's going on. In your case it may be as simple as doing: `reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0], max(x[1], y[1])))`

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! I'm gonna read the answer you linked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say you have `[("key", [13,445]), ("key", [14,109]), ("key", [15,309])]`

When this is passed to `reduceByKey`, it will *group all the values with same key into one executor* i.e. `[13,445], [14,109], [15,309]` and iterates among the values

In the first iterate `x` is `[13,445]` and `y` is `[14,109]` and the output is `max(x[1], y[1])` i.e. `max(445, 109)` which is `445`

In the second iterate `x` is `445` i.e. *max of previous loop* and `y` is `[15,309]`

Now when the second element of `x` is tried to be obtained by `x[1]` and `445` is just an `integer`, **the error occurs**

> > TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

I hope the meaning of the error is clear. You can find more details in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166009/5880706)

The above explanation also explains why the solution proposed by @pault in the comments section works i.e.

```
reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0], max(x[1], y[1])))
```