# type mismatch in scala while using reduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have separately test my error code in scala shell

```
scala> val p6 = sc.parallelize(List( ("a","b"),("b","c")))
p6: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[10] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val p7 = p6.map(a => ((a._1+a._2), (a._1, a._2, 1)))
p7: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, String, Int))] = MapPartitionsRDD[11] at map at <console>:26

scala> val p8 = p7.reduceByKey( (a,b) => (a._1,(a._2, a._3+b._3)))
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, (String, Int))
 required: (String, String, Int)
       val p8 = p7.reduceByKey( (a,b) => (a._1,(a._2, a._3+b._3)))
```

I want to use `a._1` as the key so that I can further use `join` operator, and it is required to be (key, value) pairs. But my question is, why there is a `required` type while I am using reducing function? I think the format is set by ourselves instead of something regulated. Am I wrong?

Also, if I am wrong, then why it is `(String, String, Int)` required? Why it is not something else?

ps: I know `(String, String, Int)` is the value type in `(a._1+a._2), (a._1, a._2, 1))` which is the map function, but the official example shows that the reduce funtion `(a, b) => (a._1 + b._1, a._2 + b._2)` is valid. And I think all of these including my code above should be valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the types. Reduce by key is method on `RDD[(K, V)]` with signature:

```
def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V): RDD[(K, V)]
```

In other words, both input arguments and the return argument have to be of the same type.

In your case `p7` is

```
RDD[(String, (String, String, Int))]
```

where `K` is `String` and `V` is `(String, String, Int)`, so the function used with `reduceByKey` must be

```
((String, String, Int), (String, String, Int)) => (String, String, Int)
```

A valid function would be:

```
p7.reduceByKey( (a,b) => (a._1, a._2, a._3 + b._3))
```

which would give you

```
(bc,(b,c,1))
(ab,(a,b,1))
```

as a result.

If you want to change the type in `byKey` method you have to use `aggregateByKey` or `combineByKey`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know that it is regulated that the input and the return of `reduce` function should be the same

Answer (score 2):

your `p7` is of `p7: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, String, Int))]` but in your `reduceByKey` you have used `(a._1,(a._2, a._3+b._3))` which is of type `(String, (String, Int))`

The output type of `p8` should also be `p8: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, String, Int))]`

so defining like the following should work for you

```
val p8 = p7.reduceByKey( (a,b) => (a._1, a._2, a._3+b._3))
```

You can read [my answer in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166009/5880706) for more detail on how reduceByKey works

and [this one should help too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49313182/5880706)