# Python list group by key

Tags: python, dictionary, math

I have a list  :

```
x = [[17, 2], [18, 4], [17, 2], [18, 0], [19, 4],
     [17, 4], [19, 4], [17, 4], [20, 4], [17, 4],
     [20, 4], [17, 4], [17, 4], [18, 4], [17, 4]]
```

I'd like to sum all second value when the first is the same.

Ex : 17 = 28...

I try to make a dict with :

```
d = {}
for row in x:
    if row[0] not in d:
        d[row[0]] = []
    d[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

The result is

```
{17: [2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
 18: [4, 0, 4], 19: [4, 4],
 20: [4, 4]}
```

I didn't find a way to sum the values.

Comment: You are taking the sum of all numbers

Comment: Since you are interested in the sum and not in the list, replace `d[row[0]] = []` with `d[row[0]] = 0` and `d[row[0]].append(row[1])` with `d[row[0]] += row[1]` to actually sum the elements instead of listing them.

Comment: Related question: [Reduce by key in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933189/reduce-by-key-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) if the list is sorted (and you can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to ensure that):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

d = {key: sum(grp) for key, grp in groupby(sorted(x, key=itemgetter(0)))}
```

In this case [`itemgetter(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is a more efficient shortcut for `lambda x: x[0]`.

In your original case, you could either maintain a running sum or sum afterwards. To sum the dictionary you already have:

```
d = {k: sum(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

To maintain a running sum:

```
d = {}
for k, v in x:
    if k in d:
        d[k] += v
    else:
        d[k] = v
```

A shorter way of doing the same thing would be to use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
d = {}
for k, v in x:
    d[k] = d.setdefault(k, 0) + v
```

Comment: Can you please share your thought, about why itemgetter(0) is more efficient than lambda? I am not questioning it, just trying to understand. I would write with lambda, because to me it's more readable and explicit that, for each inner list, I want to sort/group/filter by the first/second element.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque. Sure. `itemgetter(0)` is specifically written in C (in CPython) to make it a more efficient way of providing a sort key. I've added links to the docs for all the functions I'm recommending.

Answer (score 1):

Using defaultdict:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for lst in x:
...   a, b = lst
...   d[a] +=  b
>>> d
defaultdict(int, {17: 28, 18: 8, 19: 8, 20: 8})
```

Comment: You can just do `for a, b in x:`

Answer (score 0):

Here we are:

```
x=[[17, 2], [18, 4], [17, 2], [18, 0], [19, 4], [17, 4], [19, 4], [17, 4], [20, 4], [17, 4], [20, 4], [17, 4], [17, 4], [18, 4], [17, 4]]
d = {}
for row in x:
    if row[0] not in d:
        d[row[0]] = 0
    d[row[0]] += row[1]

print(d)
```

and the output is

```
{17: 28, 18: 8, 19: 8, 20: 8}
```

Comment: `d[row[0]] = row[1]` should be `d[row[0]] = 0`

Comment: You're adding the first element from each group twice otherwise. You can trivially see this for `20`: `4 + 4 = 8` but you're reporting `4 + 4 + 4 = 12`